# FK Constraint when adding using servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, dao

I have a code that adds values to two tables. However, what happens is im having a Foreign Key constraint in the reference table whenever I add. This is my code:

```
    insert into `employee-personal-information`(lastName,firstName,gender,contactNo,age,address,email)
```

select applicantLastName,applicantFirstName,applicantGender,applicantContactNumber,applicantAge,applicantAddress,applicantEmail from applicant a
where a.applicantID=?;

But at the same time, I also execute this query when I press the add button:

```
    insert into `employee-safeguard-information` (license) select a.applyingFor from applicant a where a.applicantID=?;
```

The problem with this code is that the data I am trying to insert in the employee personal information table is being updated but the code in the safeguard information does not update. I get an FK constraint. What can I do to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Which is your FK in employee-safeguard-information?

Comment: employeeID. This is auto increment. I have an applicant table which transfers data to the employee table and this is what my inserts are for. Reference table is employeeID from the personal information